# Using super-cutoff to reduce Direct Source to Drain Tunnelling

Tags: low-power, vlsi, leakage-current

I was wondering if anyone had any insight on how useful it would be to reduce direct source to drain tunnelling by applying negative gate bias voltages on sub-10nm FinFETs. Has anyone looked at this before?

From what I know, direct source to drain tunnelling current is an exponential function of the barrier height, so with negative gate bias voltages, wouldn't the effective barrier height increase, thus resulting in exponential reductions in leakage current?

Quick follow-up question: if negative gate bias voltages can help to reduce DSDT, is there any data/insight on to what degree we can reduce leakage current, given that with sufficiently negative gate-bias voltages GIDL current will become the dominant leakage mechanism?

Comment: GIDL = Gate Induced Drain Leakage, at increasingly negative voltage drain leakage increases again.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen tunneling from the source to the drain, but I have seen it in the high field that is generated from the drain edge to the gate.  I use tunneling on my floating gates, so I think I would have noticed the effects on my thin-ox devices.  What you seem to actually be describing is decreasing the drift current.

With a FinFET, you have the that magical 70mV per decade, and I'm not sure how much tunneling actually exists.  I make devices on a SOI process, but let's assume that you have a bulk process, so you could change the depletion depth.  You could change the barrier and thereby change the threshold, but then you have to ask about why you'd want to add the complexity when you could just use a threshold implant.  I have 7 different thresholds in my last kit.  This is one of those situations where I know a lot, but cannot tell you a lot on numbers, but let's go to the Kappa = 1, at 70mV per decade, if you bias the well by 70mV, you get a decade of current.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. From my understanding, direct source to drain tunnelling is supposed to dominate leakage in the sub 7nm technologies, the 70mV per decade corresponds to subthreshold leakage, which will be dwarfed as channel length decreases. What I'm asking is if it would be possible to reduce direct source to drain tunnelling by applying a negative gate bias voltage, and if so, how much room do we have to reduce direct source to drain tunneling leakage before GIDL starts to play an effect.

Comment: no.  It's a quantum effect, you'd have to increase the effective barrier thickness, and you cannot electrically modify the barrier in that direction.  All you can do is decrease Vds.  I've never personally worked with a FET below 10nm on the bench.  Also, be mindful that the models are terrible for these devices.  We make our won and they are not BSIM based.   If you want to prove out the problem, make a band diagram and find where you get the highest fields.  The high fields are the electrically thin barriers.   You can then work the probability functions to see how much current you get.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I understand that the current is a strong function of barrier width, but from my understanding, tunnelling through a barrier also has a strong dependence on barrier height; can't we modulate this with Vgs? Isn't that how Tunnel FETs are supposed to work?